# JList: scale rows to fit width of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, scale, jlist

I inserted a `JList` inside a `JFram`e at `BorderLayout.CENTER`, but I can't get the rows to fill the entire width of the `JFrame`.  Right now, the rows are left justified and too small to fill the entire width.  Would placing the list inside of a `JPanel` with another `LayoutManager` help?

Comment: You should try calling `JFrame#pack()`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Adding a JPanel will not help any further. But you should provide some more context. How is your list going to be laid out?